# Getting : TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'filePath.replace('file://', '')') while uploading a blob to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I am developing an small React Native POC with firebase storage in which a user selects image and uploads it to firebase storage under `/uid/` directory.
I am using `react-native-firebase` for using firebase in the application.

I have the `uri` of the image with which i am creating its blob using `RNFetchBlob` and then trying to upload the blob to firebase.

Here is the code for handling the blob making and uploading.

```
handleUploadTask = (mime = 'application/octet-stream') => {
    const {imageSource} = this.state;
    this.setState({uploading: true});

    const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
    const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;

    fs.readFile(imageSource.uri, 'base64')
        .then((data) => {
            return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` })
        }).then(blob => {
            console.log('going to upload');
            this.uploadBlobToFirebase(blob);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error('fs error:', error);
        })
}
```

and here is the `uploadBlobToFirebase`

```
uploadBlobToFirebase = (blob) => {
    const currentUserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const path = `/${currentUserId}/`;
    const unsubscribe = firebase.storage().ref(path).putFile(blob).on(
        firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
        (snapshot) => {
        const  progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        //restricting progress to be shown with only 0,2,4,... 98, 100.
        if (progress % 2 == 0) {
            this.setState({
                uploadProgress: progress
            })
        }

        if (snapshot.state === firebase.storage.TaskState.SUCCESS) {
            this.setState({
                uploading: false,
            }, () => {
                //TODO: should also add this image to flatlist.
                //Get download url and set to image in flatlist.
                Alert.alert('Upload completed');
            })

          }
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
                uploading: false,
            }, ()=>{
                unsubscribe();
                console.error(error);
            })
        },
      ); 
}
```

The function `handleUploadTask` is called on an onPress of a upload button and runs fine till `console.log('going to upload')` and then ends up into the catch with error:

> 'fs error:', { [TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'filePath.replace('file://', '')')]
>         line: 115903,
>         column: 41,
>         sourceURL: 'http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false' }

I am totally blank here. Not able to find the `file.replace` which is causing issue and why. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`putFile` expects a string path to a file located on native storage.

You'll need to save your blob to a file in temporary storage on the device then provide the path to that temporary file to the `putFile` method.

React Native Firebase does provide some statics that can help with locating certain directories on the device, e.g. where the temporary directory is located via `firebase.storage.Native.TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY_PATH`. See [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/storage/reference/storage#Native) for the docs of these.

It's designed like this as transmitting files/blobs over the React Native bridge would be a big performance hit vs keeping everything native.

Based on your example code you should be able to do the following;

```
firebase.storage().ref(path).putFile(imageSource.uri).on(/* ... */);
```

The reference docs with examples for putFile are located here: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/storage/reference/Reference#putFile