# How do you save a Blob to temporary native storage in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

Goal: in a React-Native project, write a Blob to firebase/storage, by saving the blob to temporary native storage first. I'm using `react-native-firebase`, not the js Firebase SDK. so I have to use RN-Firebase's `.putFile()` method. which takes a file path. Im guessing that its not as easy as using the response object's path from react-native-image-crop-picker, or else the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53686553/getting-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-filepath-replace), wouldn't have said you need to save the blob to tmp storage and use the file path of the BLOB, not the image.

contents of my existing upload method:

```
const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
    let uploadBlob = null;
    // update storage ref to work with react-native-firebase
    const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref(uid).child('profileImg');
    fs
        .readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
        .then((data) => {
            return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` });
        })
        .then((blob) => {
            uploadBlob = blob;
            // update to use react-native-firebase binding
            // return imageRef.putFile({file-Path-of-blob}, {metadata})

            // firebase js SDK version
            // return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime });
        })
        .then(() => {
            uploadBlob.close();
            return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
        })
        .then((url) => {
            console.log('Returning Download URL: ' + url);
            uploadImgSuccess(dispatch, 'Image upload successful...');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            uploadImgFail(dispatch, 'Image  upload failed: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
}
```

How do you do the intermediate step of saving the blob to storage once its created, and retrieve the path to be able to use in `.putFile()` method?